# Infinite series of a product

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Let $a_n = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (r+i)$, with $0<r<1$. I  want to find the infinite series
$$ 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\,\frac{a_n}{n!}.
$$

I tried to look at the bounds $ r^n < a_n < (r+n-1)^n$, but the upper bound is not a good one, because $\sum_{0}^{\infty} n\,\frac{(r+n-1)^n}{n!}$ diverges. The ratio test also doesn't work because
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}/(n+1)!}{a_n/n!}=1.$$
Is the above series convergent? If so, what is the value of that?

Comment: I would check out the Pochhammer symbol and binomial theorem

Comment: Agree with @AaronHendrickson. For further exploration you might study $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\, n \frac{a_n}{n!} z^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The product can be written as,
$$ \displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(r+i)=r(n-1)!\binom{r+n-1}{n-1} $$
Therefore the sum is,
$$ \displaystyle S = r\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r+n}{n}$$
The partial sum gives us,
$$ \displaystyle S_k =r\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{r+n}{n} = r\binom{k+r+1}{k} $$
So it seems it would diverge very quickly.

Comment: What if I change $a_n = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (r+\alpha\,i)$ for $\alpha<1$ ;)

Answer (score 2):

By comparing individual terms, we easily have, for $n\ge 1$
$$a_n > r\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdots (n-1) = r(n-1)!.$$

Thus each term in the sum (after $n=0$) is greater than $r>0$, so the series diverges by comparison to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$.

Comment: What if I change $a_n = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (r+\alpha\,i)$ for $\alpha<1$ ;)

Comment: @moonlight That sounds like a new question to me.

Comment: If I change $a_n = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (r+\alpha\,i)$ for $\alpha<1$, then it converges by the ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

Using Pochhammer symbols
$$a_n = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (r+i)=r (r+1)_{n-1}$$
$$b_n=n \frac {a_n}{n!}=\frac{\Gamma (n+r)}{\Gamma (n) \,\Gamma (r)}\implies \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1+\frac r n \quad >0 \quad \forall r,n$$
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p b_n=\frac{p \,\Gamma (p+r+1)}{(r+1)\, \Gamma (p+1)\,\Gamma (r)}$$ Using Stirling approximation
$$S_p=\frac{p^{1+r}}{\Gamma (r) } \Bigg[\frac{1}{(r+1) }+\frac{r}{2 p}+ O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\Bigg]$$